# "Why do you think they did that?"

Tags: adverbios, preguntas

Consider this English sentence:

> Why do you think they did that?

I think this can easily be interpreted in two ways:

- a) You think they did that. Why do you think that? (example answer: "I
  think they did that because they admitted it.")
- b) In your opinion, what was the reason why they did that? (example answer: "I think they did that because they thought it would be
  fun.")

So I kind of have a few questions:

1. How would I say "why do you think they did that?"
2. Does the same confusion exist in Spanish between the meanings a) and b) above?
3. If yes to #2, how might I try to sort that confusion out in Spanish?

I wanted to try myself, but just ignore me if I'm wrong. Here's my attempt for #1:

> Por qué crees que han hecho esto?

For #2, I'm guessing that maybe the same confusion can exist because "por qué" feels like it sort of means "because of what" in this context.
If I'm right about #2, I have no clue about #3.

Comment: In addition to the issues you raise, there is the issue of "por qué" versus "para qué".  This is a distinction that is not carefully made by English speakers.  It's the distinction between cause and purpose.  Unintended ambiguity in English between these two results in much missed communication.

Comment: I'm going to throw in a 3rd interpretation of the English sentence. The first person is unsure that the second person is thinking that "they did it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pido perdón por si interpreto mal la pregunta, pues desde mi punto de vista, planteas una cuestión con trampa, pues estás utilizando la forma neutra de los pronombres demostrativos "esto, eso, aquello" sin el contexto que conlleva su utilización y que ya se han expresado o que se van a expresar a continuación en la oración anterior o próxima.

> **Ese**
>
> **Neutro eso**. ◆ Pl. esos, esas. ◆ En aceps. 4-7, las formas ese y esa, y
> sus plurales respectivos, pueden escribirse con acento (ése, ésa,
> etc.) cuando existe riesgo de ambigüedad.
>
> 5. pron. dem. m., f. y n. El que o lo que acaba de mencionarse, o el que o lo que va a ser mencionado. Ejem. Tipos como **esos** no se encuentran
>    todos los días. **Eso** es lo que quieres, que me vaya.
>
> https://dle.rae.es/ese

De esta manera y en este caso en particular, da igual que digas;

- ¿Por qué crees que han hecho esto?
- ¿Por qué crees que hicieron eso?
- ¿Por qué crees que hicieron aquello?

Lo único que se deduce es una distancia espacio-temporal de algo que actualmente es impreciso y que en nada resuelve la cuestión.

Por tanto, dependerá a que te refieras con los pronombres "esto, eso o aquello", que son los que están sustituyendo a ese algo, para deducir cual es el origen de la "**creencia**" o de esa "**opinión**" para realmente posicionarla en el marco que corresponde, pues sin contexto, no sabemos interpretar el verbo "**creer**", es decir, no podemos considerar un juicio de valor sobre una cosa que pensamos que es verdadera, que fue u ocurrió como creemos o pensamos que paso, pero tampoco, a falta de contexto, podemos saber si lo que vamos a expresar es una "**opinión**" en la que se carece, aún más si cabe, de aquellas posibles certezas. Así en función de la secuencia, se podría utilizar el tiempo verbal más idóneo.

Comment: Thanks @Diego! 1. If I understand you correctly, "¿Por qué crees que han hecho esto?" is grammatically correct but vague. Is that right? If that's right, is there a clearer way to ask the question, depending on what I mean? 2. If I understand you correctly, "esto" would often be inappropriate depending on the context. Would it be appropriate if I were translating the following English sentences? "You said that they ran away. Why do you think they did that?"

Comment: Aunque puede variar resumo. 1. Estás en lo cierto, pues no se sabe lo que hicieron. Es correcto siempre que el emisor y el receptor sepan a lo que se refieren, es decir, sepan que es "eso". 2. Exactamente. ¿Por qué crees que hicieron eso? Busca una opinión  general del interlocutor. Ej. ¡Algo habrán hecho! ¿Por qué lo harían? Busca en el interlocutor una respuesta que responda directamente a una motivación. Ej. Por que si no los mataban. ¿Por qué lo han hecho? Busca que el interlocutor responda con una información general con las limitaciones del caso. Ej. La radio ha dicho que eran menores.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. How would I say "why do you think they did that?"

Depending on the context:

- *¿Por qué crees que lo hicieron?* (at some point in the past)
- *¿Por qué crees que lo han hecho?* (recently, with present consequences)
- *¿Por qué crees que lo hacían?* (recurrently in the past)

> 2. Does the same confusion exist in Spanish between the meanings a) and b) above?

Yes, the same ambiguity exists in those examples.

> 3. If yes to #2, how might I try to sort that confusion out in Spanish?

> a) You think they did that. Why do you think that?

*¿Qué te hace pensar que lo hicieron?* (replace *hicieron* with *han hecho* or *hacían* if necessary)

> b) In your opinion, what was the reason why they did that?

*¿Cuál crees que fue su motivo para hacerlo?* (replace *fue* with *ha sido* or *era* if necessary)

Comment: Thanks @aerobiomat! This is a great answer. I'm marking the other one only because @Diego has given me a few answers that I didn't mark as the answer.

Comment: If I wanted to translate your last 2 sentences more literally, I think it would be something like this: a) "What makes you think they did it?" b) "What do you think was their reason for doing it?" Does that sound right? As an alternative for b), could I say this? "¿Cuál crees que ha hecho hacerlo?" Not sure that makes sense. I'm trying to say "What do you think caused them to do it?"

Comment: Your first translations sound right to me (warning, English is my 2nd language). Regarding the alternative for b), "cuál" is used when choosing between a limited number of options, while "qué" is used as an open question. Also, you need an indirect object "les" (them). So it would be "¿**qué** crees que **les** ha hecho hacerlo?". But we don't like using the same verb consecutively, so we can replace the first one with other options, like  "motivar", "obligar", "forzar"... For example, "¿qué crees que les ha obligado a hacerlo?. As before, you can use "ha obligado" / "obligó" / "obligaba".